# checkout error when using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, boost, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to checkout from http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk with TortoiseSVN and I encounter a weird problem recently, which keeps me from the nightly update of the repository.

The error message returned from the Tortoise is:

```
Error: REPORT of '/svn/boost/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body:   
Error: connection was closed by server (http://svn.boost.org)  
Finished!:
```

I googled around and got some questions like this one but haven't found any reasonable solutions to it.

How to solve this problem?

P.S.:

The configuration of my laptop:

Windows 7 Ultimate
TortoiseSVN 1.6.14-64bit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy, try disabling it. Also, try using

```
https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk
```

instead.

Comment: Your reply enlightens me but it still doesn't work properly....I receive another error message like:  Error: REPORT of '/svn/boost/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body: Secure Error: connection truncated (svn.boost.org) Finished!: What's the problem this time?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to checkout fine. Make sure your network connection is stable and there are no interruptions. If possible, try checking out using a better network.

Comment: Your reply enlightens me. The network connection seems stable enough because I'm checking out other repos on my platform simultaneously.... Or, should I stop these operations and close the internet explorer? I've no idea about this....